# Naming a generic property after its type

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, reflection, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# class like this (extra properties removed for simplicity):

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to somehow dynamically name `MyProperty` after the type of `T`?

For example, if I instantiate my class as:

```
MyClass<MyOtherClass> myClass = new MyClass<MyOtherClass>();
```

I would want the name of `MyProperty` to instead be `MyOtherClass`. I have looked around Google and StackOverflow but have not found anything like this. Is this possible somehow? Maybe using reflection?

---

**EDIT:**

First, if you are going to downvote my question, I would appreciate it if you would comment on why.

Second, maybe it would help to clarify why I want to do this. This class is being returned by an API. It has some information on it related to errors, along with a generic-typed property that represents an entity being returned. However, when the API call is made, the response looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "MyOtherClass": {
      // properties here
    },
    "Errors": [
      {
        "ErrorCode": 1,
        "Message": "sample string 1"
      },
      {
        "ErrorCode": 1,
        "Message": "sample string 1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like "MyOtherClass" above to be the actual name of the entity (generic type).

Comment: No; that's totally impossible.  How would you refer to it in the class?

Comment: You could (but shouldn't) use `dynamic`.

Comment: This would completely defeat the pupose of generics, which is to define base functionality in the base class.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I added some clarification in my question. I'm not sure how `dynamic` would help in this situation - am I missing something? (Also, if it's not a good practice to use it then I don't necessarily want to go down that route.) I am not trying to change functionality, only the name of the property, or somehow otherwise find a way to have a better name for the response to my API call.

Comment: @SLaks You probably meant `ExpandoObject`, not `dynamic`.

Comment: The typical Property is named `Value` in these cases: e.g. `Lazy<T>`, `Nullable<T>`, etc. since these simply encapsulate a value.

Comment: You would have to either encapsulate an `ExpandoObject` as alluded to by @Servy; or have `MyClass<T>` descend from `DynamicObject`. I've done this but as SLaks points out, you still have an issue with accessing the property outside of the DynamicObject base type. You would be forced into declaring `dynamic obj = new MyClass<SomeClass>() as DynamicObject` [*if this is even possible*]. Anyway, the long and short of it is that this is a very messy proposition and will be difficult to convey the meaning and purpose of the code.

Comment: Maybe you could write a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to do this, or something in the serialization / deserialization portion, instead of trying to make your class weird to match the weird data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend `DynamicObject`:

```
public class MyClass<T> : DynamicObject
{
    private T property;

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (binder.Name == typeof(T).Name)
        {
            result = property;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if (binder.Name == typeof(T).Name && value is T)
        {
            property = (T)value;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

which you can use like:

```
dynamic myObj = new MyClass<string>();
myObj.String = "value";

string value = myObj.String;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. After more thought, however, I decided that having a generic name for the returned type is actually fine. I decided against this method because it caused issues with my generated documentation (since there is no longer a compile-time property with a public getter) and also for some of the reasons mentioned in the comments. Still, you answered my question perfectly in terms of what I said I wanted, so I still believe it deserves to be the accepted answer. Thanks!